# How do I ensure I return encoded text for requests that have encoded text?

Tags: security, http, grails, encoding, ascii

In a Grails architecture, we have some requests where it is possible to send put in `%0d` and `%0a` in the request paramaters.  This is Ascii encoded text for newline and carriage return.
In this request the parameters sent over are also returned.  This means we should be sending back `%0a` `%0d`  but we are not.  You can actually see the new line and carriage return in the response.

I am told this is a security risk because we interpret the text.  IS this correct?

And is there a grails solution whereby you ensure none of Controllers whether they be returning Json to Ajax request or Model to a GSP decode the encoded text.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [security section](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/security.html) of the grails docs - especially the [XSS Prevention](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/security.html#xssPrevention) section.

If you're not encoding the request parameters - users of your app could inject own code to attack your application.

I've no details about your app, but you should encode your parameter as html. 
You could set this as default within your `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.views.default.codec = "html"
```

If you set this default you have to be aware of double encoding.
This could happen if a `tagLib` or a plugin also encodes the parameter as html explicitly.